# How to add an Object to the stage with nested code in AS3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

I'm busy developing my first application using the AS3.0 language.

I built the full application in Flash Professional, it worked, but it lacked performance.

Now, I'm rebuilding it in Flash builder, so it's more optimised, and it's running great.

Although I've hit a snag.

In Flash Pro, it was very easy for me to add movieclips to the stage, with code nested inside them, so when I added the object, all the code worked like a charm.

In Flash Builder, I have NO clue on how to achieve the same effect... I'm so close to being finished but have no idea how to achieve this.

I've tried making external classes, but with no programming background, it's very hard to find a solution when I don't know where to begin...

SO in short:

HOw to you add objects to your stage using pure AS3 code,
I need to add a graphic object to my stage
And add simple mouse interactivity to it.

Any responses, links, chuckles at me, would be greatly appreciated

Shane

Answer (score 0):

The following code would add a movieclip to the stage, with a line drawn from 0,0 to 100,100 . Provided you are writing this code in the Main class.

var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

addChild(mc) ;

mc.moveTo(0,0)
mc.lineTo(100,100) ;